# Distinguish between requests coming from Azure and Okta

Tags: azure-active-directory, okta, scim, scim2

During provisioning phase, what's a reliable way to distinguish between requests coming from Azure ActiveDirectory and Okta?

We're implementing SCIM and SSO in our app. To aid user UX, we would like to render better errors to users, for cases when they would like to log in using wrong SSO provider. For example, if users were provisioned from Okta and attempts to log in using Azure (don't know why would he do that – but still), we'd like to tell them to use Okta instead.

It appears as if I am missing something obvious, as am I failing to locate relevant topics (e.g. source / origin of the server) in the SCIM 2.0 protocol, as well as Azure/Okta documentation.

Answer (score 1):

That would be your SCIM connector's responsibility to capture originating call by IP to understand which system created this user. So you need to look at that direction, to add an additional attribute in your system depending on the SCIM caller's IP

Comment: +1 to the suggestion to use source IP addresses. I question the need for this, however - as the original question stated, they aren't sure why someone would do this - but there may be valid reasons. As an example, migration between IDPs - a customer may have originally started on one of the IDPs and would be migrating to the other. End users typically don't have much concern over what IDP is being used either, so even if you were to go down this path it sounds like surfacing any warnings to the IT/app admins would make more sense.

Comment: I guess @Zollnerd it's just for the sake of a better UX to give them a meaningful feedback on an unsuccessful login attempt with a wrong IdP. In your scenario, if they have migrated from one to another, choosing a wrong IdP for SSO might not result in an error, if the asserted user is found. +1 for bringing the idea :)